# Преобразование byte[] в string

Tags: c#

Получаю сообщение от сервера по сокету. Метод `Receive` в качестве параметра принимает `byte[]`, и, так как я не знаю какого размера будет сообщение, выделяю память с запасом, например, 100 байт.

```
byte[] byteMessage = new byte[100];
socket.Receive(byteMessage);
```

После получения конвертирую в строку с помощью:

```
string strMessage = Encoding.Default.GetString(byteMessage);
```

В итоге строка `strMessage` — строка, которая мне нужна, но с кучей пробелов в конце.

Вопросы:

1. Можно ли получить по сокету размер получаемого сообщения?
2. Если нельзя, то как определить конец полученого сообщения?

Comment: Некропостинг, конечно, но: НИ В КОЕМ СЛУЧАЕ не используйте `Encoding.Default`. Потому что `Encoding.Default` означает ANSI-кодировку на клиенте, которая с огромной вероятностью не совпадает с кодировкой, в которой шлёт данные сервер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, вам стоит использовать значение, возвращаемое методом Receive, которое, как [подсказывает MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8s4y8aff(v=vs.110).aspx) не что иное, как число полученных байтов. Впрочем, если это не так (честно говоря, не проверял), то можете сделать вот что:

```
string strMessage = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes.Where(x => x != 0).ToArray());
```

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно Receive возвращает количество переданных байт.

Answer (score 1):

`Receive` возвращает количество прочитанных байтов. Также есть перегруженный метод [Receive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/26f591ax%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), используйте его.

Пример

```
 var buffer = new byte[128];
 string mes = string.Empty;

 do
 {
    int count = socket.Receive(buffer, buffer.Length, 0);
    mes += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, count);
 } while(socket.Available > 0)
```