# Как получить строку шестнадцатеричного представления массива byte[]?

Tags: c#, .net

Есть некоторый массив байтов, и надо получить из него "этот же" массив байтов (строку его шестнадцатеричного представления).

Как это реализовать?

```
byte[] btarr = new byte[] {0xFF, 0xAA, 0x00, 0xAD, 0xAF};
string res = "";
res = btarr.ToString();
// Ожидаю строку: FFAA00ADAF
```

Comment: наверное вам сюда https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/3a733s97%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: `BitConverter.ToString( btarr ).Replace( "-", "" )`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Преобразование byte\[\] в string](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/273257/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-byte-%d0%b2-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Или так:

```
string res = btarr.Select(b => b.ToString("X2")).Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1 + s2);
```

> тогда уж и без select можно было – @Grundy

Справедливое замечание, добавлю и такой способ:

```
string res = btarr.Aggregate("", (s, b) => s += $"{b:X2}");
```

Comment: тогда уж и без select можно было

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
string res = string.Concat(btarr.Select(b => b.ToString("X2")));
```