# Байт массив в шестнадцатеричное число

Tags: c#

Есть байт массив, нужно получить из этого байт массива строку в виде шестнадцатеричного числа. Например "1A49B0146C93"

Comment: Было ж уже: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/640945/Как-получить-строку-шестнадцатеричного-представления-массива-byte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var array = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
var str = BitConverter.ToString(array).Replace("-", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 2):

Ещё один вариант, вручную:

```
byte[] arr = { 0x1A, 0x49, 0xB0, 0x14, 0x6C, 0x93 };
var s = string.Concat(arr.Select(b => b.ToString("X2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
```